# How to get the last nth record for each group in a rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, group-by

I have a table named Game which is filled with individual players statlines from all their games in an nhl season. The fields That I am concerned with here are games_played which = n for the nth game of a player in the season. 
and name which is the players name.

Essentially I am trying to figure out how to grab the nth last game for each player.

For instance I know the following query can get me the last game for each player

```
Game.group(:name).having('games_played = MAX(games_played)')
```

However when I try the following (lets say n is 10)

```
Game.group(:name).having('games_played=MAX(games_played)-10')
```

I get no results

and in fact if I explicitly do something like

```
Game.group(:name).having('games_played=16')
```

I only get the last game of players who played exactly 16 games, instead of the 16th game for all players. (Which I guess explains the no results of the previous query)

How do I go about getting the nth last game for each player?

Is this even the right way to query this? I also have a player table where a player has_many games, and a game belongs_to a player. Should I be taking advantage of that?

Comment: Can you explain **nth last** a bit more?

Comment: Have you considered the `take` function? For ex. adding `.take(n).last` to the end of the query?

Comment: @Pavan, by nth last I mean the the game that is n-1 games before the most recent one played. So 2nd last wound be the second most recent game, 10th last would be the 10th most recent. I want to get that game for each different player.

Comment: @AndresEhrenpreis take(n) will give me n games total for my entire table, instead of n games for each unique name in the table. Likewise last will change that n to just 1 game total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the nth last game for a specific player, it would probably be easiest to start by finding the player.

```
player = Player.find_by(name: "user3692508")
```

then you can find the players games with:

```
player.games
```

To get the nth last game, you can order it by `games_played` in descending order, then limit it to one result and offset it with the offset you want:

```
player.games.order(games_played: :desc).limit(1).offset(0)
```

If you do an offset of 0, you will get the last game. If you do an offset of 1 you will get the 2nd last game and so on.

This is assuming your player `has_many :games` and the game `belongs_to :player`

By using a sub query you can get the nth last game for each player.(it looks like a mess.....)

```
offset = 1

sub_query = "SELECT 'sub_game'.id FROM 'games' as sub_game WHERE 'sub_game'.'player_id' = games.player_id ORDER BY 'sub_game'.'games_played' DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET #{offset}"

Game.joins(:player).where("games.id IN (#{sub_query})").order(id: :desc).group(:player_id)
```

With this solution, you would sort the games for each player in the sub query and do the offset there first.

Comment: Thanks, thats very helpful. 
Is it possible to have one query that returns the nth last game for every player, or should I be set on one query per player?

Comment: To get the last game for each player you can do `Game.joins(:player).order(games_played: :desc).group(:player_id)`, but am not sure how you would add an offset to it.

Comment: I added a solution to my answer that will give you the nth last game for each player